# Insert item after every nth item in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am iterating through a list of products and displaying them in cards.  I'd like to display a promotion after every 18th product listed:

```
<div
     v-for="(prod, index) in products"
       :key="index"
       class="w-full md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/4 mb-8 px-2
     >
     <promotion v-if="(index % 18 == 0) && index != 0" ></promotion>
     <product-card v-else :product="prod"></product-card>
</div>
```

The way I have this written now, the promotion is displayed but it is inserted in place of the item with the matching index.  How do I place the promotion before or after the nth item without replacing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To preserve grid css, you can put them under a `template` and use `v-for`

```
<template v-for="(prod, index) in products">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/4 mb-8 px-2" 
        v-if="(index % 18 == 0) && index != 0" 
        :key="'promotion-${index}'">
    <promotion></promotion>
  </div>
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/4 mb-8 px-2" 
      :key="'product-${index}'">
    <product-card :product="prod"></product-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I didn't realize that v-for could be used on a template. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to remove the v-else here inside the product-card element

`<product-card :product="prod"></product-card>`

Comment: I'm using flexbox and have set each item in the loop to span 1/4 of a row, so this causes the promotion and the product card to be displayed inside of the 1/4 row space

Comment: It seems like a css problem from here.  What happens if you put the css on the promotion element and the product-card element instead of the div?